# Integral of square root of normal random variable over the real line

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, radicals

I'm trying to find a closed form expression for the following integral:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \exp \bigg(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \bigg)dx$$

This integral is essentially $E[\sqrt{x} \mathbf{1}_{x>0}]$, where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Comment: Did you read [this question guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)? Please add context and tries to solve the integral! It seems like this uses the error function or some form of it. Is this an expected variable expression. We can try to find a sum expression.

Comment: Why would you expect a closed form solution?

Comment: Why do you expect it converges? It is not an integral of a Gaussian. Your integral is like this $\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{x^2}dx$ that diverges

Comment: Should there be a negative sign on the exponent?

Comment: The exponential term was missing a minus sign, I've edited it now.